Nuxt 3 With Vite Production Issue: Works in Development but Not in Production
I'm experiencing an issue with my Nuxt 3.6.5 application. The app runs perfectly with npm run dev, but when I build and start it using npm run build and npm run start, it doesn't work as expected.
Here are the details:
Nuxt version: 3.6.5 (tested on other versions as well, same issue)
Node version: 18.19.0
Vuex version: 4
I've set up the store globally using $store as I did in Nuxt 2. This setup works fine in the development environment, but in the production environment, it seems that Nuxt is not reactive and doesn't update on data changes.
For instance, if the store is used in a computed property and something changes in the store, Nuxt does not detect this change in the production environment.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on what might be causing this problem?
package.json

"dependencies": {
    "@boindil/vue-file-agent-next": "^1.0.5",
    "@fawmi/vue-google-maps": "^0.9.72",
    "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs-pro-vue-v3": "^1.5.0",
    "@hcaptcha/vue3-hcaptcha": "^1.3.0",
    "@morev/vue-transitions": "^3.0.2",
    "@vee-validate/nuxt": "^4.12.6",
    "@vee-validate/rules": "^4.12.6",
    "@vee-validate/yup": "^4.12.8",
    "apicache": "^1.5.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "card-validator": "^8.1.1",
    "cookie-parse": "^0.4.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "country-list": "^2.2.0",
    "country-telephone-data": "^0.6.3",
    "credit-card-type": "^9.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "currency-codes": "^2.1.0",
    "currency-symbol-map": "^5.1.0",
    "detect-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.2",
    "httpxy": "^0.1.5",
    "humanize-duration": "^3.27.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "lightweight-charts": "^2.0.0",
    "maska": "^2.1.11",
    "mobile-device-detect": "^0.4.3",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "nested-property": "^2.0.1",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
    "nuxt": "^3.6.5",
    "nuxt-tradingview": "^1.3.1",
    "nuxt3-vuex-module": "^1.1.0",
    "phone": "^2.3.19",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.4",
    "reconnecting-websocket": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.2.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.15",
    "text-decoding": "^1.0.0",
    "to-time": "^1.0.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.3",
    "vee-validate": "^4.12.6",
    "vue": "^3.4.27",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.11.0",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^3.0.0-alpha.6",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0",
    "vue-slider-component": "^4.1.0-beta.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.16",
    "vue3-lottie": "^3.3.0",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0",
    "winston": "^3.13.0",
    "ws": "^7.5.3",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^1.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.2.2",
    "@vite-pwa/nuxt": "^0.6.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.4.21",
    "consola": "^3.2.3",
    "defu": "^6.1.4",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.4.2",
    "hookable": "^5.5.3",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.5.2",
}

console errors:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'refs')
at Hc (entry.c639020f.js:13:33476)
at g (entry.c639020f.js:13:38271)
at D (entry.c639020f.js:13:39629)
at E (entry.c639020f.js:13:38952)
at S (entry.c639020f.js:13:38770)
at g (entry.c639020f.js:13:38161)
at Js.Y [as fn] (entry.c639020f.js:13:42481)
at Js.run (entry.c639020f.js:9:1518)
at y.update (entry.c639020f.js:13:42762)
at j (entry.c639020f.js:13:42789)

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'emitsOptions')
at QT (entry.c639020f.js:13:6006)
at be (entry.c639020f.js:13:41549)
at ee (entry.c639020f.js:13:41296)
at g (entry.c639020f.js:13:38187)
at St (entry.c639020f.js:13:43631)
at X (entry.c639020f.js:13:43177)
at O (entry.c639020f.js:13:39939)
at S (entry.c639020f.js:13:38789)
at g (entry.c639020f.js:13:38161)
at St (entry.c639020f.js:13:43631)
Uncaught (in promise) non-precached-url: non-precached-url :: [{"url":"/"}]
at O.createHandlerBoundToURL (http://localhost:3000/workbox-7cfec069.js:1:13245)
at Object.createHandlerBoundToURL (http://localhost:3000/workbox-7cfec069.js:1:14828)
at http://localhost:3000/sw.js:1:13129
at http://localhost:3000/sw.js:1:565

entry.c639020f.js:13 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'emitsOptions')
at QT (entry.c639020f.js:13:6006)
at be (entry.c639020f.js:13:41549)
at ee (entry.c639020f.js:13:41296)
at g (entry.c639020f.js:13:38187)
at St (entry.c639020f.js:13:43631)
at X (entry.c639020f.js:13:43177)
at O (entry.c639020f.js:13:39939)
at S (entry.c639020f.js:13:38789)
at g (entry.c639020f.js:13:38161)
at St (entry.c639020f.js:13:43631)

entry.c639020f.js:13 TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'bum' of 'y' as it is null.
at ce (entry.c639020f.js:13:46029)
at ft (entry.c639020f.js:13:45371)
at de (entry.c639020f.js:13:46337)
at ft (entry.c639020f.js:13:45574)
at de (entry.c639020f.js:13:46337)
at ft (entry.c639020f.js:13:45574)
at de (entry.c639020f.js:13:46337)
at ft (entry.c639020f.js:13:45574)
at de (entry.c639020f.js:13:46337)
at ft (entry.c639020f.js:13:45574)


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Depends on where you host it. Also, does it work if you build and preview it locally? Regarding Node, the current LTS is v20. Why are you using Vuex with Vue3? Any errors in the console? Can you check the devtools to find out the issue using this one? Overall, very difficult to help you here because you have a very specific situation here + you do not provide a repro. Issue with Workbox, consider removing the service worker to debug. Overall, you have a lot of errors to troubleshoot here.

You can leave the errors part as a screenshot, doesn't make sense to copy that one. Also, the issue is far more than just the package.json here, might be a project with a whole issue overall.

no it doesn't work in preview either

Then it's not a "production" issue (hence not a platform/hosting problem) but some code issue that you do have.
